# Facebook comment plugin font color

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I'm trying to change the font color of the comment within the facebook comment plugin. I have some css on it which works, but when I tried to change the color of the font, it didn't do anything.

Here is the page URL: http://cardspoiler.com/Bootstrap/Munter/Theme/Counterfeit_coin_bootstrap.html

and here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Cardspoiler - Counterfeit Coin</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../../Cardspoiler_Title_Logo.tif">
    <meta name="description" content="BlackTie.co - Free Handsome Bootstrap Themes" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="themes, bootstrap, free, templates, bootstrap 3, freebie,">
    <meta property="og:title" content="">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-v=2.1.5.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,300,200&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<style>
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #232526;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #232526 , #414345);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #232526 , #414345);
    margin: 0em;
}
a { cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; }
footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 130px;
    z-index: 200;
    background: #e4e6e5;
  background-color: rgba(228,230,229,.9);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    border-top: solid transparent 5px;
}
#content{
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}
#text-content{
    padding: 175px 0 0 0;
}
.col-aligncenter{float: none;margin: 0 auto;}
#locator { /* for the FB comments plugin */
  position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 775px; top: -270px; height: 100px; width: 500px; z-index: 200;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
}
.fb_container {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: white;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" data-activeslide="1">
        <div class="container-fullwidth">

            <!-- .navbar-toggle is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../Navbar/Home.html">Cardspoiler</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" >
                <ul class="nav row">
                    <li data-slide="1" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="home" title="Home"><span class="icon icon-home"></span> <span class="text">Home</span></a></li>
                    <li data-slide="2" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="warrior" title="Warrior" class="external nav"><span class="icon icon-filter"></span> <span class="text">Warrior</span></a></li>
                    <li data-slide="3" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="druid" title="Druid"><span class="icon icon-leaf"></span> <span class="text">Druid</span></a></li>
                    <li data-slide="4" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="priest"title="Priest"><span class="icon icon-plus-sign"></span> <span class="text">Priest</span></a></li>
                    <li data-slide="5" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="paladin" title="Paladin"><span class="icon icon-heart"></span> <span class="text">Paladin</span></a></li>
                    <li data-slide="6" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="hunter" title="Hunter"><span class="icon icon-screenshot"></span> <span class="text">Hunter</span></a></li>
          <li data-slide="7" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="mage" title="Mage"><span class="icon icon-fire"></span> <span class="text">Mage</span></a></li>
          <li data-slide="8" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="shaman" title="Shaman"><span class="icon icon-tint"></span> <span class="text">Shaman</span></a></li>
          <li data-slide="9" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="warlock" title="Warlock"><span class="icon icon-user"></span> <span class="text">Warlock</span></a></li>
          <li data-slide="10" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="rogue" htitle="Rogue"><span class="icon icon-eye-close"></span> <span class="text">Rogue</span></a></li>
          <li data-slide="11" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="minions" title="Minions"><span class="icon icon-chevron-up"></span> <span class="text">Minions</span></a></li>
          <li data-slide="12" class="col-12 col-sm-1"><a id="spells" title="Spells"><span class="icon icon-chevron-down"></span> <span class="text">Spells</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 active-menu"></div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
  <div class="table-responsive" id="content">
        <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <td valign="top">
          <img src="../../../../0/Counterfeit_Coin.png" align="left" class="img-responsive">
          <div id="center">
                    <div id="text-content">
          <font color="#888888" style="font-size:300%">
            Counterfeit Coin
          </font>
            <br>
s            <br>
            <font style="font-size:160%" color="9B764C">
            Cost:
          </font>
                    <font style="font-size:130%" color="#888888">
                    0
                    </font>
                    <br>
            <font style="font-size:160%" color="9B764C">
            Type:
            </font>
            <font style="font-size:130%" color="#888888">
            Spell
            </font>
            <br>
            <font style="font-size:160%" color="9B764C">
            Text:
            </font>
            <font style="font-size:130%" color="#888888">
            Gain 1 mana crystal this turn only.
                        <div id="right">
                            <div id="locator">
                            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                <div class="fb_container">
                              <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/cody.bontecou" align="right" data-width="500px" data-numposts="3"></div>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                        <br>
                        <br><br>
                        <br><br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
            </font>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
  <center>
        <footer>
            <div class="footer" id="footer">
                    <div class="container.customcontainer">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div align="right">
                                                <font color="888888" size="4%">CARDSPOILER.COM</font>
                                                <font color="9B764C" size="3%">
                                                <br>
                                                Freedom to know
                                                                                    </font>
                                                <br>
                                                                                        <br>
                                                <font size="2%" color="666666">
                                                We are here to bring you visual, leaked spoilers for all of <br> the cards you love within a simple gallery.
                                                <br>
                                                                                    </font>
                                                <font color="#333333">
                                                    <a href="mailto:help@cardspoiler.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:#9B764C;font-size:70%;">CONTACT US</a>
                                                    <a href="../../Privacy_Policy.html" style="text-decoration:none;color:#9B764C;font-size:70%;">PRIVACY POLICY</a>
                                                </font>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                                                        <div align="left">
                                            <font color="#888888" size="2%">
                                                <a href="MSoG.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:#888888;">Mean Streets of Gadgetzan</a>
                                            </font>
                                            <br>

                                            <font color="#888888" size="2%">
                                                <a href="ONiK.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:#888888;">One Night in Karazhan</a>
                                            </font>
                                            <br>

                                            <font color="#888888" size="2%">
                                                <a href="WotOG.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:#888888;">Whispers of the Old Gods</a>
                                            </font>
                                            <br>

                                            <font color="#888888" size="2%">
                                                <a href="tLoE.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:#888888;">The League of Explorers</a>
                                            </font>
                                            <br>

                                            <font color="#888888" size="2%">
                                                <a href="TGT.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:#888888;">The Grand Tournament</a>
                                            </font>
                                            <br>

                                            <font color="#888888" size="2%">
                                                <a href="BrM.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:#888888;">Blackrock Mountain</a>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                        </footer>


</body>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack-v=2.1.5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '220939261681295',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
  };
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   $(function(){
   var navMain = $("#nav-main");
   navMain.on("click", "a", null, function () {
       navMain.collapse('hide');
   });
});
$(".fb_container").css("height","400px");
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: use: div._4q1v span a { color: red; }

Comment: Pasting this into my <style> did nothing.

Comment: Oh woops, forgot that with frames that won't work. (You have to paste that line of code in the <style> of the frame). You might want to take a look at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe . Javascript seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring out a simple solution to my problem. 
Within `<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/cody.bontecou" align="right" data-width="500px" data-numposts="3"></div>` I was able to add `data-colorscheme="dark"` into it. The code now looks like:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/cody.bontecou" align="right" data-width="500px" data-numposts="3" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```